# I am looking to render templates stored in a database into my angular application, These templates do have String Interpolation in

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am looking to render templates stored in a database into my angular application, These templates do have String Interpolation in and I need to have these values populated when rendered

component.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="getTemplateData(testHtml)"></div>
```

component.ts

```
  public testHtml: string = 
  `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>`;
  
  getTemplateData(html: string) {
    return  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);    
  }
```

My main issue here is I get the html string to render but the String Interpolation variables don't populate just stay {{title}} and {{hero}} but the html elements render perfectly

Comment: `innerHTML` just parses a string for use as native HTML, you lose functions of the Angular templating engine like interpolation/binding/event handling. Typically you can use pipes/directives to substitute the lost functionalities, e.g. in your case you could have a pipe which takes in an object of your variables and swaps them into your HTML string using `.replace()`. It's a shame that we have to do this but it is an option at least if the effort is worth it to remain dynamic

Comment: @nate-kumar this did work but only issue now is I ended up loosing the functionality of my `(click)` events I wanted to add, Do you have a possible work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

As Nate-kumar say, if you only need interpolation you can create a pipe

```
@Pipe({ name: 'resolve', standalone: true })
export class ResolveValues implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private satinizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform(testHtml: string, parent: any, changed: boolean) {
    const data = testHtml.match(/{{.+}}/g);
    let result = testHtml;
    if (data != null) {
      data.forEach((x) => {
        const variable = x.match(/{{(.+)}}/);
        result = result.replace(x, variable ? parent[variable[1]] : '');
      });
    }
    return this.satinizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(result);
  }
}
```

Then, if you have two variables

```
  changed: boolean = false; //really is a value that will be true/false/true/false
  testHtml: string = `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>`;
```

You can use

```
<div [innerHTML]="testHtml|resolve:this:changed"></div>
```

See that the variable "changed" it's only necessary if you are planning change the value of the variables that you interpolate, e.g.

```
change()
{
    this.myHero='Angular the best' //change the variable
    this.changed=!this.changed  //change to force angular repaint
}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-agznif?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Not the ideal answer, no need to over engineering something by creating a Pipe(). Angular has template literals!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using template literals:

```
`<h1>${title}</h1>`
```

Comment: sadly, template literals not work if you're getting the data from an API or from a file. You can check easy: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-agznif?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fassets%2Fdata.json)

Comment: False... it does work cause i use it all the time. your maybe not getting the data on time then or your not getting any data at all!

Comment: @Eliseo... of course its not going to work cause you put the "<h1>${title}</h1>" inside of a json file, which no one does and is the incorrect way to use it. Your example is NOT going to work that way.

Comment: I'm charmin if I was wrong (I love learn new things), But I can not make work your way looking for a .json (or an API). I tryed `this.variable=`${res.data}`` or `this.variable=`res.data` or in json `"data":"`<h1>${title}</h1>`"` and not worked